# Fill RDLC report with Json Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I'm trying to fill out the RDLC report with Json, but it doesn't return anything other than the columns.

[image: How it shows]

I got this Json result:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "11",
        "grade": "1",
        "netweight": "10.00",
        "code": "1",
        "initials": "CFF",
        "specie": "Tilapia",
        "scientificname": "Pende",
        "activity": "Offloading Truck",
        "voyage": "CFF2208",
        "vessel": "CHICOA FISH FARM",
        "currentbatch": "0",
        "tprocessID": "PRC01",
        "batchno": "123"
    }
]
```

I created a Json Property:

```
Namespace Data

    Public Class Tilapia
        <JsonProperty("grade")>
        Public Property grade As String

        <JsonProperty("netweight")>
        Public Property netweight As Decimal

        <JsonProperty("specie")>
        Public Property specie As String

        <JsonProperty("voyage")>
        Public Property voyage As String

        <JsonProperty("batchno")>
        Public Property batchno As String

        <JsonProperty("scientificname")>
        Public Property scientificname As String

    End Class
```

Fetch data:

```
Public Class Custom_batch

    Public Shared Function GetTilapia() As List(Of Tilapia)
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim reader As StreamReader
        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.160/v2/api/tilapia/tilapia/read_distinct.php"), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Headers("Authorization") = "46464-44874-444469-554777"
        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim rawresp As String
        rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Dim results As List(Of Tilapia) = New List(Of Tilapia)()
        results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Tilapia))(rawresp)
        Return results
        MsgBox(results)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then I build the class, and added to the project the .DLL file in the references, Then Added to Dataset and selected the datasource (Its strange that I can't find the GetTilapia() function in the Available Datasets).

[image: Datasets]

Tried to run but only returns the columns.

What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: You're not showing the code where you set the retrieved JSON data as the DataSource for the report - something like Report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", GetTilapia() )).  The results you show look like a report with no data.

Comment: Tried to add, but can't find the GetTilapia(), that's the problem.

Comment: @JonRoberts thanks for the idea, just solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding the GetTilapia() function code in my project, then called:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
Dim rds = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", GetTilapia())
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```